# UIBackButtonItem setTitlePositionAdjustment does not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to make left inset for custom UIBackButtonItem (there should be place for image), but this method just do nothing. Why?

```
[item setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(100, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following method:

```
- (void)setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:(UIOffset)adjustment forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

Comment: Works perfect. Than you!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance! :)